# What is the current recommended approach to manage/stop a spring-batch job?

Tags: spring-batch, autosys, spring-batch-job-monitoring

We have some spring-batch jobs are triggered by autosys with shell scripts as short lived processes.
Right now there's no way to view what is going on in the spring-batch process so I was exploring ways to view the status & manage*(stop)* the jobs.

*Spring Cloud Data Flow* is one of the options that I was exploring - but it seems that may not work when jobs are scheduled with Autosys. 
What are the other options that I can explore in this regard and what is the recommended approach to manage spring-batch jobs now?

Comment: find the pid for this job and issue "kill -9 pid" to stop the related process from unix shell

Comment: that is efficient and will take care of stopping part of the problem, but it will also leave the job instance in the meta-tables in an inconsistent and undesirable state. More over it doesn't give a view of what's happening on the batch without querying the meta-tables.

Comment: from autosys issue "sendevent –E KILLJOB –J job_name"

Comment: regarding, meta-table entries, that have to be rolled back manually.

Comment: I understand that you are talking specifically from an autosys view how to kill a process. It just that I'm looking to stop a process gracefully in spring-batch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop a job, you first need to get the ID of the job execution to stop. This can be done using the `JobExplorer` API that allows you to explore meta-data that Spring Batch is aware of in the job repository. Once you get the job execution ID, you can stop it by calling the `JobOperator#stop` method, please refer to the [Stopping a job](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/job.html#stoppingAJob) section of the reference documentation.

This is independent of any method you used to launch the job (either manually, or via a scheduler or a graphical tool) and allows you to gracefully stop a job and leave the repository in a consistent state (ready for a restart if needed).

Comment: Thanks, I had thought of using the `JobExplorer + JobOperator` and exposing a REST API on top of it. I though it would be good to ensure that I do not attempt something which is already available for use as a library.

Comment: If you want something ready to use, there is Spring Cloud DataFlow by VMware or [Spring Batch lightmin](https://github.com/tuxdevelop/spring-batch-lightmin) by the community. Hope this helps.